# box2d PolygonShape inside PolygonShape

Tags: box2d, physics, game-physics, libgdx

I created full screen "borders" which contains boxes (boxes should move inside this borderBox). Boxes are dynamic and borderBox is a static body. BorderBox is PolygonShape and boxes are PolygonShape too.

But when I "put" by boxes inside borderBox its automatically move out of the borderBox.

What should I do? Can I use PolygonShape to create such borders or I should just draw lines instead of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b2PolygonShape and b2CircleShape are not hollow. So you can put nothing inside these shapes. What you want to use for screen bounds is b2EdgeShape.